# Simple IE11 Bookmarklet Throwing "Object Expected" Error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, bookmarklet

I have the following code:

```
javascript:void(alert("Ok"));
```

When run as a bookmarklet, I get a "Object Expected" error at character 12 (the "v" of void).

I actually have a more complex bookmarklet I'm trying to run, which works just fine in the address bar, but gives me the same error as a bookmarklet. I boiled everything down to this simple line, and I still get the same error.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `void alert("Ok");` work?  It means the same thing. Looks like an IE bug to me.

Comment: Nope, I get the exact same error. Thanks though!

Comment: I do not get an error in IE version 11.0.9600.17690 on Windows 8.1 using a bookmarklet.